# MVC4 Azure deployment can't find WebPages or WebMatrix references

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm attempting to deploy a site to Azure automatically via GitHub and upon committing to the master branch, Azure picks it up and attempts to deploy but I get a 'deployment failed' message with errors like the following:

> App_Start\AuthConfig.cs(1,21): error CS0234: The type or namespace
>   name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Web' (are
>   you missing an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\xxxxx\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\xxxxx.UI.Web\xxxxx.UI.Web.csproj]

And

> Controllers\AccountController.cs(18,7): error CS0246: The type or
>   namespace name 'WebMatrix' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>   [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\xxxxx\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\xxxxx.UI.Web\xxxxx.UI.Web.csproj]

MVC 4 (and the WebMatrix/WebPages dependencies) are installed in my UI.Web project via NuGet, not loaded from the GAC. Copy Local is set to true on the assembly references. Any idea why I might be getting these deployment issues?

Comment: Since this is a GitHub grab and deploy, are you sure that your packages and/or bin files are actually under source control and being pushed into your repository?  Even if copy local is set to true, if you are not pushing those into your repo...they would not be found to copy

Comment: True, but since they're added via NuGet, wouldn't it install those packages upon deployment?

Comment: Nuget just downloads the packages to a packages folder and adds the appropriate references to your project so that when you build, the compiler knows where to go get them.  NuGet would not have anything to do with Azure pulling your branch and compiling the source.  Check that the packages folder in your solution is being committed to your repository so that the actual NuGet downloads are available to Azure via GitHub

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the packages folder is committed to source control as well and contains all of the required packages. I wasn't inferring that Azure would go download them, only that they should be available to Azure already since they're NuGet packages, therefore installed in the packages directory.

Comment: Gotcha. That was my only thought that might be a gotcha with your issues, I have not yet used the Azure git method of publishing, so really don't have any more insight as to what the issue could be

Comment: Download project form azure using FTP, and look what is wrong locally. In my option it is the fastest way to find a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried deploying with NuGet package restore? Then Azure should download all dependencies during deployment and GitHub isn't littered with binaries.

Just right click on a **solution** and hit "Enable NuGet Package Restore". Commit with the .nuget folder in your solution directory with packages.config in your project dir, that were created.

--
As for you current problem - you could drop your GitHub's link, that would be helpful. Maybe you used default .ignore for Visual Studio and that does prevent commiting binaries.